# Boost::Asio. In which thread is the message sent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I'm trying to understand the internal work of `boost::asio` library, which is really great. I've written a simple client that sends one message to a server.

The question is - in which thread does it really send the message?

Since I use `async_write()` method, it returns immediately after calling and doesn't send anything. I've commented the `io_service.run()` method, and after that the handler was not called (that's okay), but the message was sent! (I've checked it in server logs)

By the way, I don't use `-lpthread`, just `-lboost_system` while compiling, so I assume the whole program works in one thread and there are no "hidden" threads.

I cannot make head or tail of where was the message sent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

const std::string str("HELLO!");

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 33333);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::connect(socket, &endpoint, ec);
    boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(str),
                             [](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
                             {
                                 if (!ec)
                                 {
                                     std::cout << "Sent!" << std::endl;
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     std::cout << "Err: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                 }
    });

    //io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your "Sent!" output appear at your console? io_service.run() is needed for sure. Are you totally sure your log has net been from a previous run?

Comment: @MartinMeeser, "Sent!" appears only when the io_service.run() is uncommented, and I understand it, that's ok. I'm totally sure about the fact that the server receives messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message would have been sent (or at least queued in the network stack, perhaps to be handled by a kernel thread, or some other implementation-dependent mechanism that you shouldn't need to care about) during the call to `async_write`. There's no need to defer that, if it can be done without blocking the calling thread, which it typically can be.

The completion handler won't be called until the `io_service` is run, and is notified that the message has been sent.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. However please can you add one or two words to >The question is - in which thread does it really send the message?

Comment: Mike, thanks. Then what does the synchronous write() method do? Does it wait the responce from the kernel that the message was or wasn't sent?

Comment: @MartinMeeser: "in which thread does it really send the message?" That's a detail of the network stack implementation. It's either the thread that calls `async_write`, or one (perhaps a kernel thread) managed by the stack. Or no thread at all, if it uses DMA. It's not something the application writer should care about.

Comment: "Then what does the synchronous write() method do? Does it wait the responce from the kernel that the message was or wasn't sent?" Yes - it waits for completion and returns the result, rather than reporting the result later through a completion handler.