# Async send automatic variable using boost::asio. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm still trying to understand the work of `boost::asio` C++ library.

According to the answer on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776235/boostasio-in-which-thread-is-the-message-sent), `async_write()` method enqueues the message in the network stack and immediately returns. However, in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html) they say it is wrong to do such thing:

```
void dont_do_this()
{
   std::string msg = "Hello, world!";
   boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg), my_handler);
}
```

They insist that we need to ensure that the buffer for the operation is valid until the completion handler is called. The question is WHY? At the moment of async_write return we've already put our message in the network stack and we don't need the buffer any longer, and the automatic variable `msg` can be destroyed without serious consequences. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async_write` does not really queue the message in the network stack. Instead it queues the write to boost asynchronous tasks queue held by the `io_service`. The write to the network stack actually happens later, when you call `run` on the `io_service`. In short there is an intermediate queue.

In you case the `boost::asio::buffer` keeps a reference to 'msg' and not a copy of it. If `msg` goes out of the scope, when your message is sent to the network stack, the `buffer` is pointing to a dangling reference to a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it hasn't clarified the problem for me. In my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776235/boostasio-in-which-thread-is-the-message-sent) I don't use `io_service` at all (I know that it's not a good practice), but the message is successfully sent. I was pretty sure that only completion handlers are invoked in `io_service.run()` method.

Comment: As suggested in the other question thread, it's possible that the intermediate queue is skipped, and the message sent straight to the network. But there's no guarantee that it will happen all the time. In particular when you'll start sending many messages and the network gets busy. Also you've mentioned threads, but you don't have to use them. You can call `io_service.run()` in the same thread, later.